# How to automatically catch the day on Carbon?

Tags: laravel, api, php-carbon, clockify

[image]

I am creating through laravel a system to get clockify all the tasks done on the day between a certain time. I'm looking at carbon for some functionality to automatically catch the day, but I didn't find anything.
Does anyone know how to automatically catch the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon has the `startOfDay()` and `endOfDay()` methods:

```
$params->startDate = Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->toJSON();
$params->endDate = Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->toJSON();
```

From the Carbon docs:

````
    /**
     * Resets the time to 00:00:00 start of day
     *
     * @example
     * ```
     * echo Carbon::parse('2018-07-25 12:45:16')->startOfDay();
     * ```
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function startOfDay();

    /**
     * Resets the time to 23:59:59.999999 end of day
     *
     * @example
     * ```
     * echo Carbon::parse('2018-07-25 12:45:16')->endOfDay();
     * ```
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function endOfDay();

    /**
     * Return the ISO-8601 string (ex: 1977-04-22T06:00:00Z) with UTC timezone.
     *
     * @example
     * ```
     * echo Carbon::now('America/Toronto')->toJSON();
     * ```
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function toJSON();
````